# Why doesn't a stationary wave completely destruct, instead of just at the nodes, when the waves are in fixed positions (see examples)

Tags: waves

Example 1: I understand that two progressive waves, say π out of phase, travelling in the same direction with the same frequency and amplitude will completely destruct. This is due to the principal of superposition, with the displacements of the two waves always being the opposite of each other, hence always summing to zero. If the two progressive waves are in phase, then they will constructively reinforce.

Example 2: If two progressive waves are again π out of phase, with the same amplitude and frequency, but instead travelling in opposite directions, then there will only be certain times when they're π out of phase, hence only completely destruct at certain points, as they will then move past each other and, for example reinforce.

Example 3: However, if say two people, A and B, hold a rope and both oscillate the string so there are two progressive waves travelling in opposite directions, this is the same as the example 2, but instead A and B are in fixed positions, and hence the waves do not progress - is this correct?

If that is correct, why do they not constantly cancel. The reason why I ask is that in the 2nd paragraph, the waves were not fixed so they were able to move past each other, and hence did not always completely destruct. In example 3, the waves are in fixed positions, so doesn't this mean that they can't move past each other, and hence stay π out of phase, and therefore would always completely destruct?

I could really do with some help, thanks in advance!

Comment: In Ex 3, A and B are fixed, but they are just the source of waves.  The waves themselves travel exactly like Ex 2.  Another way to look at it:  What caused the waves in Ex 2?  Some fixed sources, undoubtedly.

Comment: Your examples #2 and #3 are essentially the same. They both result in standing wave patterns with certain fixed nodes which are always zero. In example #3, you are forcing the fixed nodes to be at locations A and B.